# JSON to Dictionary not Working? Python/PyMongo

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pymongo

I'm currently working on a simple CRUD program using Python and MongoDB with the Pymongo library.  When I run the update function, I want the results of the update_one() to be read into a JSON object which I load into a dictionary, return to the main function, and then iterate through the dictionary.  I am using json.dumps to read the raw result from the update_one() function into a json file, and then json.loads to load it into a dictionary:

```
def update(self, data: dict, updateString: dict):
        if data is not None and updateString is not None:
            resultsCount = self.database.animals.update_one(data, updateString, upsert=False)
            if resultsCount.modified_count != 0:
                print("Updated successfully")
                print("Records updated: " + str(resultsCount.modified_count))
                json_data = json.dumps(resultsCount.raw_result)
                json_dict = json.loads(json_data)
                return json_dict
            else:
                raise Exception("Update error, check your data again")
        else:
            raise Exception("Nothing to find, because a least one of the data parameters is empty")
```

I then try to iterate through this using a for loop like so:

```
 updateInfo = aShelter.update(data, updateString)
 for key in updateInfo:
     print(key, ':', updateInfo[key])
```

However, I get an error message when the code reaches inside the for loop that:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I believe that somehow I am not successfully turning the raw result into a dictionary.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: Also, earlier in development I tried to use "for d in updateInfo:  print(d)" which resulted in a massive vertical strand of text with one letter on each line.  Thus why I'm trying to iterate through as a dictionary.

Comment: Why does your `update()` method convert something to a `json` string (using `.dumps()`), and then convert it back to a `json` object (using .loads()`)?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood what format the raw result from update_one() is.  When trying to simply return to the raw result, the object was not iterable.  I thought that by converting to a json string, then an object, I would have a dictionary which it iterable using the for loop that i specified.

Comment: Also, without this transformation I get a "TypeError:  the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'UpdateResult'" message.

Comment: So what is the type of `resultsCount.raw_result`?

Comment: # dict object with more info on API call
print ("raw_result:", result.raw_result)

Comment: So based on that and your earlier comment, I tried simply returning the raw result and using the for loop on that and it worked like a charm!  Turns out that I was taking a dictionary, converting it to a json string, then into a json object, then trying to iterate through it like it was a dictionary.  I removed the dumps and loads steps and simply returned raw result and the for loop iterated through and printed all the needed info!  Thank you!

Comment: There is no way you need to involve `json` here. You need to investigate what `resultsCount.raw_result` contains (maybe you need to return a modified version). If it is a `dict` then you can iterate over it in all the normal ways. I suggest trying: `for key,value in updateInfo.items():`